# How to make data layer in xaf framework

Tags: c#, xaf

In my project I am using the xaf application framework from devexpress. How to make data layer in xaf framework. I have a third-party service in the form of a web api (http://for-example.com/bla-bla-bla-api/). And I need the web api to be the data source for my datalayer. Thanks for the replies

```
class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        XpoTypesInfoHelper.GetXpoTypeInfoSource();
        XafTypesInfo.Instance.RegisterEntity(typeof(Department));
        XPObjectSpaceProvider osProvider = new XPObjectSpaceProvider(
        @"integrated security=SSPI;pooling=false;data source=(localdb)\v11.0;initial catalog=MainDemo_", null);
        IObjectSpace objectSpace = osProvider.CreateObjectSpace();
        foreach (Department department in objectSpace.GetObjects<Department>()) {
            Console.WriteLine(department.Title + "\t" + department.Office);
        }
    }
```

So this can be done for a standard situation. And I need to use my web service instead of the connection string.

Comment: I am able to make a datalayer as described in the xaf documentation. But I don't know how to use my web api as a data source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several options for getting XAF working over Wcf or WebAPI. The following are more or less in order of complexity:

XAF supports a WCF based middle tier out of the box. See the documentation for the [middle tier security](https://documentation.devexpress.com/eXpressAppFramework/113439/Concepts/Security-System/Middle-Tier-Security-WCF-Service) and subsequent articles.

There is an [OData service wizard](https://documentation.devexpress.com/XPO/14812/Design-Time-Features/OData-Service-Wizard) with a working demo here: *C:\Users\Public\Documents\DevExpress Demos 18.2\Components\WinForms\Bin\XpoTutorials.exe*.

It is also possible to use the OData WebApi tier provided by the XAF mobile. The easiest way is to use the wizard to add a new mobile application to your existing XAF solution. Here is a [Support Centre article to get you started](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T607061/how-to-extend-xaf-web-with-restful-webservice)

There is a new SPA ASP.NET Core data service in the latest versions of XAF (18.2+). This [does not use OData](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T698384/web-api-data-service-for-xaf-app). Note that not all of the XAF modules are supported yet for this platform.